# Can't I use one of the members of my scope collection as a default for radio button?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let's say I have this controller:

```
myCtrl = function($scope)
{
    $scope.shipMethods = [{ "name": "standard",
                           "id" : 1},
                          { "name": "overnight",
                           "id" : 2},
                          { "name": "next day",
                           "id" : 3}
                         ];

    $scope.selectedShipMethod = $scope.shipMethods[0];    

    //works: $scope.selectedShipMethod = {     "name": "standard",      "id" : 1};
```

};

And I've got this in my view:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form>
        <h1>you selected {{ selectedShipMethod.name }} </h1>
        <label class="radio-input" data-ng-repeat="shipMethod in shipMethods">
           <b class="title">{{shipMethod.name}}</b> 
           <input type="radio" name="ship-method" value="{{shipMethod.name}}"
                 data-ng-model="selectedShipMethod.name" />
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm trying to set a selectedShipMethod when the user selects one of the radio buttons. But when I select either the second or third radio buttons, the label next to the first one gets updated with whatever is in selectedShipMethod.name.  But here's the ng-mystery: If I make a copy of the first item in my array and initialize $scope.selectedShipMethod to that copy, I do NOT see the issue.

It looks like there's something deeper to be understood here about radio buttons in an ng-repeat.  The actual data I'm working with will be coming from the web server has some estimated shipping dates which will change, so I'd really like to use a member of the array as the default.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdegermark/XFq56/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click a radio button, the first item in the radio button list changes - as does the corresponding label: {{ selectedShipMethod.name }}.

To understand why this is happening, we need to take a closer look at which model the radio button is actually bound to.  In the parent controller, you have initialized the selectedShipMethod to the first ship method ($scope.ShipMethods[0]) in parent scope:

```
 // bind the selectedShipMethod to the first ship method
 $scope.selectedShipMethod = $scope.ShipMethods[0];
```

This is important to remember, because the selectedShipMethod never actually changes - even when a different radio button is clicked.

To see why, take a closer look at the ng-model of the radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="ship-method" 
             data-ng-model="selectedShipMethod.name" />
```

The ng-model that the radio button is bound to is actually 'selectedShipMethod.name'.   Notice there is a '.' in the middle of the model.  According to scope inheritance rules, 'selectedShipMethod' will be resolved first by searching for the declaration of the variable in the current scope; if it is not found in the current scope, it will search for it in the parent scope, etc, until it either finds the scope variable or stops at $rootScope.  In this example, it will find it in the parent scope, which if you remember, is bound to the first ship method.

By selecting a different radio button, you are actually changing the '.name' property of the first shipping method!   This is obviously not what we want to happen.

So what is the solution?

The solution is simple - change the binding so that the selectedShipMethod is bound to the same model that is on parent scope:

```
   <input type="radio" name="ship-method" ng-value="shipMethod"
         data-ng-model="$parent.selectedShipMethod" />
```

That is exactly what we are doing when we do '$parent.selectedShipMethod'. $parent refers to the parent scope, so according to scope inheritance rules, it will find and resolve the selectedShipMethod variable in the parent scope.

You might be asking yourself at this point, is the $parent prefix really necessary? The answer is Yes.  Since the scope variable is being set (when the radio button is clicked), the setter for the scope variable is called. There is no scope inheritance resolution happening if there is no '.' in the model and a setter is used - without the $parent prefix, it would create a copy of the scope variable in child scope that over-shadows the scope variable in parent scope, effectively breaking the model binding.

Finally, we use ng-value since `shipMethod` is a model from a ng-repeat directive. When a radio button is selected,  $parent.selectedShipMethod is set to the selected `shipMethod`.  Everything works because the right model ($parent.selectedShipMethod) is being bound to the right scope - the parent scope.

I hope all this makes sense.  Here is a [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/up9YX/1/)

Comment: This is a very thorough analysis.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  Instead of setting the selected object to the first element of array, just make a copy into a new object.

http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/XFq56/3/

When you set

```
a = b[0];
```

a and b[0] are both pointing to the same object.  So, when you are setting 'a' with the radio button, you are actually changing the object b[0].

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is Reverse Binding. Try the following code:

```
  $scope.selectedShipMethod = angular.copy($scope.shipMethods[0]);
```